# flutter: webview does not allow jumping to anchors in the same html page

Tags: javascript, html, flutter

I've bumped into an annoying flutter issue where HTML anchors don't work in the `WebView`.

The full issue is here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65379

### Steps to Reproduce

I'm using webview to show localized html files. In each HTML file there are  `href` links to redirect to corresponding language files. I'm using this little class below to show the HTML as a page.

```dart
with this little class
class LocalLoader {
  Future<String> loadLocal(String filename) async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/$filename');
  }
}
class HtmlPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Completer<WebViewController> controller;
  final String htmlFile;
  HtmlPage({
    @required this.htmlFile,
    @required this.controller,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: LocalLoader().loadLocal(htmlFile),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return WebView(
              debuggingEnabled: true,
              initialUrl: Uri.dataFromString(snapshot.data,
                  mimeType: 'text/html',
                  // CAUTION
                  // - required for non-ascii chars
                  encoding: Encoding.getByName("UTF-8")
              ).toString(),
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                // CAUTION
                // - avoid exception "Bad state: Future already completed"
                if(!controller.isCompleted) {
                  controller.complete(webViewController);
                }
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          } else {
            print('undefined behaviour');
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),);
  }
}
class HelpPage extends HtmlPage {
  HelpPage(ctrl) : super(htmlFile: 'help_en.html', controller: ctrl);
}

class AboutPage extends HtmlPage {
  AboutPage(ctrl) : super(htmlFile: 'about_en.html', controller: ctrl);
}
```

And the relevant html code looks like this in each language files

```html
<p><span style="font-size: 20px;"><a href="help_en.html">English</a></span> <span class="math inline">    </span> <span style="font-size: 20px;"><a href="help_fr.html">Français</a></span></p>
```

### Repro 1

Open my app

1. Place `help_en.html` and `help_fr.html` in `assets` folder, and add the corresponding yaml section.
2. Load the initial page "help_en.html" and it shows correctly
3. Click the `Français` link on the page

**Expected results:**

We should see the `help_fr.html` upon clicking its redirection link.

**Actual results:**

We see a blank page

### Repro 2

I suspected it may have been a relative path error.  So I modified the HTML page so that the href looks like

```html
<p><span style="font-size: 20px;"><a href="assets/help_en.html">English</a></span> <span class="math inline">    </span> <span style="font-size: 20px;"><a href="assets/help_fr.html">Français</a></span></p>
```

But the result is the same as in Repro 1.

Logs

```
E/InputMethodManager(24228): b/117267690: Failed to get fallback IMM with expected displayId=215 actual IMM#displayId=0 view=io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.InputAwareWebView{f259a5f VFEDHVC.. .F...... 0,0-2075,706}
E/InputMethodManager(24228): b/117267690: Failed to get fallback IMM with expected displayId=215 actual IMM#displayId=0 view=io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.InputAwareWebView{f259a5f VFEDHVC.. .F...... 0,0-2075,706}
```

No `flutter analyze` errors

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.22.0-9.0.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021, locale en-CN)
    • Flutter version 1.22.0-9.0.pre at /Applications/flutter
    • Framework revision 7a43175198 (10 days ago), 2020-08-28 23:18:04 -0400
    • Engine revision 07e2520d5d
    • Dart version 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-73.0.dev)
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Applications/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Applications/Android/sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /Applications/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.7)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.7, Build version 11E801a
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 49.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.13.2

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • ONEPLUS A6000 (mobile)   • <my udid>                                 • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)
    • MyiPhone (mobile) •<my udid> • ios           • iOS 13.6.1
    ! Device emulator-5554 is offline.

• No issues found!
```

## UPDATE

I dug further and thought this might be related to #27086, but it turned out to be even worse, see below:

### Attempt

To work around this issue, I thought about merging `help_en.html` and `help_fr.html` into a single html file and turn the href's into anchors so that I can bypass the local assets reference issue by jumping within the same html file.

In theory, this would work.

### Trouble

However, to my surprise, this didn't work either! I still see blank pages when trying to go to the anchors. The same anchors work fine in an Electron test app and in the browsers.

This time I got an error in Android Studio's console

```sh
E/InputMethodManager(28987): b/117267690: Failed to get fallback IMM with expected displayId=259 actual IMM#displayId=0 view=io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.InputAwareWebView{b193667 VFEDHVC.. .F...... 0,0-2075,706}
I/chromium(28987): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml%22%20lang=%22%22%20xml:lang=%22%22%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%3Cmeta%20charset=%22utf-8%22%20/%3E%0A%20%20%3Cmeta%20name=%22generator%22%20content=%22pandoc%22%20/%3E%0A%20%20%3Cmeta%20name=%22viewport%22%20content=%22width=device-width,%20initial-scale=1.0,%20user-scalable=yes%22%20/%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctitle%3E%20%3C/title%3E%0A%20%20%3Cstyle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20code%7Bwhite-space:%20pre-wrap;%7D%0A%20%20%20%20span....E4%BA%8E%3C/h1%3E%0A%3Ch3%20id=%22section%22%3E%3C/h3%3E%0A%3Ch2%20id=%22%E5%8A%A8%E5%90%AC-version-1.0%22%3E%E5%8A%A8%E5%90%AC%20version%201.0%3C/h2%3E%0A%3Cp%3ECopyright%C2%A9%202020%20NExT%20%E5%B7%A5%E4%BD%9C%E5%AE%A4%E7%BE%A4%3C/p%3E%0A%3Cp%3E%E7%89%88%E6%9D%83%E6%89%80%E6%9C%89%3C/p%3E%0A%3Cp%3E%E9%9A%90%E7%A7%81%E6%94%BF%E7%AD%96%3Cspan%20class=%22math%20inline%22%3E%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%3C/span%3E%E7%94%A8%E6%88%B7%E6%9C%8D%E5%8A%A1%E5%8D%8F%E8%AE%AE%3C/p%3E%0A%3C/body%3E%0A%3C/html%3E%0A#helpen", source: data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml%22%20lang=%22%22%20xml:lang=%22%22%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%3Cmeta%20charset=%22utf-8%22%20/%3E%0A%20%20%3Cmeta%20name=%22generator%22%20content=%22pandoc%22%20/%3E%0A%20%20%3Cmeta%20name=%22viewport%22%20content=%22width=device-width,%20initial-scale=1.0,%20user-scalable=yes%22%20/%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctitle%3E%20%3C/title%3E%0A%20%20%3Cstyle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20code%7Bwhite-space:%20pre-wrap;%7D%0A%20%20%20%20span.smallcaps%7Bfont-variant:%20small-caps;%7D%0A%20%20%20%20span.underline%7Btext-decoration:%20underline;%7D%0A%20%20%20%20div.column%7Bdisplay:%20inline-block;%20vertical-align:%20top;%20width:%2050%25;%7D%0A%20%20%20%20div.hanging-indent%7Bmargin-left:%201.5em;%20text-indent:%20-1.5em;%7D%0A%20%20%3C/style%3E%0A%20%20%3C!--%5Bif%20lt%20IE%209%5D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%20src=%22//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%0A%20%20%3C!%5Bendif%5D--%3E%0A%20%20%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%20src=%22help_lang.js%22%20type=%22module%22%3E%3C/script%3E%0A%20%20%3Cstyle%3E%0A%20%20/*%0A%20%20%20%20CAUTION:%20must%20use%20embedded%20style%20for%20standalone%20html%20with%20-s%0A%20%20*/%0A%20%20/***************%0A%20%20Global%0A%20%20***************/%0A%20%20/*%0A%20%20%20*%20I%20add%20this%20to%20html%20files%20generated%20with%20pandoc.%0A%20%20%20*/%0A%20%20html%20%7B%0A%20%20font-size:%20100%25;%0A%20%20overflow-y:%20scroll;%0A%20%20-webkit-text-size-adjust:%20100%25;%0A%20%20-ms-text-size-adjust:%20100%25;%0A%0A%20%20/*--scrollbarBG:%20%23CFD8DC;*/%0A%20%20--scrollbarBG:%20%232a2f39;%0A%20%20--thumbBG:%20%2390a4ae;%0A%20%20/*CAUTION:%20required%20for%20background%20parallax%20*/%0A%20%20height:%20100%25;%0A%20%20/*CAUTION%20end:%20required%20for%20background%20parallax%20*/%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20body%20%7B%0A%20%20color:%20%23e5e5e5;%0A%20%20font-family:%20Arial,%20Helvetica,%20sans-serif;%0A%20%20font-size:%2012px;%0A%20%20line-height:%201.7;%0A%20%20padding:%201em;%0A%20%20margin:%20auto;%0A%20%20max-width:%2042em;%0A%20%20/*CAUTION:%20required%20for%20background%20parallax%20*/%0A%20%20background:%20url('images/bg-logo.png')%20no-repeat%20top%20right,%20%232a2f39;%0A%20%20height:%20100%25;%0A%20%20background-attachment:%20fixed;%0A%20%20background-position:%20center;%0A%20%20background-repeat:%20no-repeat;%0A%20%20background-size:%20cover;%0A%20%20/*CAUTION%20end:%20required%20for%20background%20parallax*/%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20a%20%7B%0A%20%20color:%20%237c8694;%0A%20%20text-decoration:%20none;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20a:visited%20%7B%0A%20%20color:%20%230072ae;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20a:hover%20%7B%0A%20%20color:%20%2306e;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20a:active%20%7B%0A%20%20color:%20%23faa700;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20a:focus%20%7B%0A%20%20outline:%20thin%20dotted;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20*::-moz-selection%20%7B%0A%20%20background:%20rgba(255,%20255,%200,%200.3);%
E/InputMethodManager(28987): b/117267690: Failed to get fallback IMM with expected displayId=259 actual IMM#displayId=0 view=io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.InputAwareWebView{b193667 VFEDHVC.. .F...... 0,0-2075,706}
```

### Verdict

So to me this is beyond the fuss of running an http server to work around a very simple webpage doc. It is actually a much more serious bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be fixed by now. The best workaround I found was to create local HttpServer.

For simplicity - I used [local_assets_server](https://pub.dev/packages/local_assets_server) package, which basically wraps around [HttpServer](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-io/HttpServer-class.html) and simplifies serving bundled resources. But it is extremely easy to implement this functionality directly using [HttpServer](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-io/HttpServer-class.html), especially if you use this solely for serving static HTML content. Here is my implementation using [local_assets_server](https://pub.dev/packages/local_assets_server):

```
class HelpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? tag;

  HelpScreen({this.tag});

  @override
  _HelpScreenState createState() => _HelpScreenState();
}

class _HelpScreenState extends State<HelpScreen> {
  late LocalAssetsServer _webServer;
  late int _webServerPort;
  bool _webServerListening = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _startServer();

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: () {
            if (_webServerListening) {
              return WebView(
                initialUrl: 'http://localhost:$_webServerPort/help.html#${this.widget.tag ?? ""}',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
        });
  }

  _startServer() async {
    _webServer = new LocalAssetsServer(
      address: InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4,
      assetsBasePath: 'assets/html',
    );

    await _webServer.serve();

    setState(() {
      _webServerPort = _webServer.boundPort;
      _webServerListening = true;
    });
  }
}
```

Make sure you allow local HTTP networking on Android by creating/updating `android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

... and then referencing it from `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest ...>
    ...
    <application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ...>

        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

... and on iOS in `ios/Runner/Info.plist`:

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>    
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```